# IBM Netezza and node.js

Tags: node.js, netezza

Anyone knows if there is a driver for the IBM Netezza database for node.js? Google search yielded nothing.

Also how is the support for other RDBM in node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Followed by IBM document about Netezza. They just support
"Develop with R, Hadoop, Java, C, C++, Python, Fortran " language only.
So you can not directly call Nettiza from javascript in nodejs.
To use Netezza u need to develop ur own netteza DB moudle by using C or C++ language.

http://www-05.ibm.com/il/software/netezza/pdfs/IBM_Netezza_Analytics_USEN.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There are jdbc, odbc and ole-db drivers to connect to Netezza. 
They're available on the IBM support page, though you need an entitled support account to download them.
I imagine connecting to netezza from node.js is possible using those.

edit: the documentation is available [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/topic/com.ibm.nz.datacon.doc/c_datacon_introduction.html)

Comment: I'm not that keen on RMDBs drivers. jdbc is out of question because it requires java right? If I use odbc or ole-db do I need to manually write the bindings to node.js in C or C++? I am new with node.js (and not that good of a C++ programmer) would I be able to pull it off?